# Microsoft Enterprise Library cannot write log through ODBC

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc, enterprise-library

In my application MEL is set up to use database listener based on GenericDatabase (ODBC) like this:

```
GenericDatabase db = new GenericDatabase(_connectionString, OdbcFactory.Instance);
TraceListener traceListener = new FormattedDatabaseTraceListener(db, _writeLogStoredProcName, _addCategoryStoredProcName, _formatter);
```

ODBC is set up to connect to SQL Server driver. "WriteLog" stored procedure looks as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WriteLog]
(
    @EventId int, 
    @Priority int, 
    @Severity nvarchar(32), 
    @Title nvarchar(256), 
    @Timestamp datetime,
    @MachineName nvarchar(32), 
    @AppDomainName nvarchar(512),
    @ProcessID nvarchar(256),
    @ProcessName nvarchar(512),
    @ThreadName nvarchar(512),
    @Win32ThreadId nvarchar(128),
    @Message nvarchar(1500),
    @FormattedMessage ntext,
    @LogId int OUTPUT
)
AS 

    INSERT INTO [LOG] (
        EVENTID,
        PRIORITY,
        SEVERITY,
        TITLE,
        [TIMESTAMP],
        MACHINENAME,
        APPDOMAINNAME,
        PROCESSID,
        PROCESSNAME,
        THREADNAME,
        WIN32THREADID,
        MESSAGE,
        FORMATTEDMESSAGE
    )
    VALUES (
        @EventId, 
        @Priority, 
        @Severity, 
        @Title, 
        @Timestamp,
        @MachineName, 
        @AppDomainName,
        @ProcessID,
        @ProcessName,
        @ThreadName,
        @Win32ThreadId,
        @Message,
        @FormattedMessage)

    SET @LogID = @@IDENTITY
    RETURN @LogID
```

When I execute the following code I get an error:

```
LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
logEntry.Message = "Test Message";
logEntry.Priority = 1;
logEntry.Categories.Add("Error");

LogWriter logWriter = GetLogger();

// ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Procedure or function 'WriteLog' expects parameter '@EventID', which was not supplied.
logWriter.Write(logEntry);
```

For some reason parameters are not passed into my stored procedure and I verified it through SQL Server profiler. When the SP gets executed profiler shows only this:

```
WriteLog
```

I have also tried to change SP parameter's title to have various naming such as: @eventid, @EVENTID, @eventID, @EventID, but nothing worked.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any info about my problem, so I ended up creating my own custom logging library with Blackjack and hookers.